# iphone - IB display an image name that been deleted (reference and trashed)

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

when i choose a uiimageview in interface builder  it display in the image pick list (of this imageivew) an image name that been deleted from this project (deleted:reference and trashed),
why the image name still on the list ?

Comment: This question needs some grammar and clarity. Maybe add some pictures to illustrate your point better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interface Builder has gotten out of synch with Xcode. I think that in the current version, *File*->*Reload All Class Files* will synchronize resources as well. If not, restart Interface Builder.

### Edit01:

I reproduced the error. The name of the image remains in the UIImageViews attribute inspector's *image* popup menu even after the fall has been deleted from the project and the image disappears Interface Builder's image library.

I found that selecting the name in the popup menu, deleting the name in popup menu, saving and then restarting Interface Builder cleared the name.

It looks like a minor bug in Interface Builder wherein the popup menu choices don't update properly. I don't think it will cause any direct problems as long as you don't select the wrong name.

Comment: it still displayed in the list and as a missing image in the library.